# Server Layout for Web-, API-, Database-, VPN- and SIP Server

Tags: vpn, web-server, database, sip

i have the possibility to redo our Server Infrastructure - i need your advices and best practices to design a good foundation for future expansion.
As we are a quite small company with a very limited customer base (<100) security and desaster recovery (even as an error by another employee) is the main concern. *So as the suggested question is not really helpful as capacity planning is not the main concern.*
The main feature of our infrastructure is collecting Data from our tools worldwide and present them to the customers. As well as support for maintenance (eg SIP).
main Features currently:

- Webserver
- VPN Server
- SIP Server
- Database

i have 3 Ubuntu Servers

- 2x Ryzen 5 5600, 32GB RAM
- 1x i7 2600, 16GB RAM

my currently planned Layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAyUP.jpg

- so i would put the i7 Server as Webserver
- one Ryzen for an VPN, SIP and DB API Server
- one Ryzen for the Database

I Thought about having one managing Server is maybe weak (if i screw it up, everything is ... screwed). Should i add another old Server (eg PC) to "outsource" the VPN Server? Running 4 PCs might seem a bit overkill, but electricity cost is not that big of an issue.
Do you have some good ideas here?

Thanks in advance!

Johannes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: thanks for your advice, i will study it later on. It is not about capacity planning, more about security and desaster recovery as i think we can handle our Load (the i7 is my only server right now)

Comment: What are requirements? Resilency, downtime, performance considerations? Other equipment, e.g. switches, UPS? Probably, move something into datacenter to increase availability.

Comment: thanks nikita for your point of view. As our Data might be seen as "sensible" we came to it that we want to host our infrastructure ourself. 
thanks for asking for requirements! availability is indeed not *that* critical, so a downtime here and there might be acceptable. resiliency is maybe what we are striving for. What do you think in terms of Virtualization? I could easily take snapshots and a desaster recovery will be a task of under an hour to get it back online?! So i could separate functions logically (SIP, VPN) and increase security compared to hosting on it on one Server. Thanks!